# established a inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to establish a inequality of the form $x^{-c} \le K(c,t)(1+x^2)^{t}$ where $c<1/2$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$. that is we need to choose suitable $ K(c,t)$ and $t$ such that the above inequality hold. Can someone help me please?Thanks.

Comment: You cannot, because $x^{-c}\,$ is unbounded as $x\rightarrow 0\,$ for $c>0\,$, while  $K(c,t)(1+x^2)^{t}\,$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $K(c,t)>0$ (what happens if $K(c,t)<0$?). Expanding @gammaster 's comment, just rewrite you inequality as
$$
1 \leq K(c,t) x^c (1+x^2)^t.
$$
For $0<c<1/2$ there is no hope: taking the limit as $x \to 0$ we find $1 \leq 0$.

For $c<0$, say $c=-d$ with $d>0$, we find
$$
1 \leq K(c,t)\frac{(1+x^2)^t}{x^d}.
$$
In other words,
$$
\inf_{x >0} \frac{(1+x^2)^t}{x^d} > 0.
$$
This is true (I hope!) if and only if $2t \geq d$.